# Can't build my web application when integrating bootstrap template

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, webstorm

I'm totally new to Node.js meteor and all development outside of visual studio.
When I go in the console and add bootstrap like this :

```
npm install twitter-bootstrap
```

It gets installed and adds all the bootstrap files in my solution but when I run my application with meteor it says

```
Process finished with exit code 254
```

No more information. No errors. If I delete all the bootstrap files, it builds and run just fine. Any idea what might be causing this?

I've tried looking for the exit code meaning but I can't find it for my IDE and I'm a bit clueless as for why simply adding those packages without even referencing them anywhere in the project might cause my application not to run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `npm` packages in your project folder like that. It will create a `node_modules` sub-directory that meteor will treat like any other project folder, i.e., it will interpret all the files in it. That's not what you want. Either do the `npm install` in a super-directory, or, better yet, use the meteor `meteorhacks:npm` package (https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm):

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

and then add the npm dependency to your packages.json file.

{
  "twitter-bootstrap": "2.1.1"
}

But the real question is: why do you need this package? bootstrap3 is already part of the standard meteor packages, i.e., you already have full access to bootstrap, incl. javascript.

Comment: Right that's exactly what it was doing. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use atmosphere meteor packages called [mizzao:bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootstrap-3) by running the commend

`meteor add mizzoa:bootstrap-3`

Alternatively if you want to use npm packages you must add [meteorhacks:npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) packages.

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm
 npm install twitter-bootstrap`

You can specify all the required npm packages inside a packages.json file.

```
{      
 "gm":"1.16.0",
 "twitter":"0.2.12",
 "twitter-bootstrap":"2.1.1",
}
```